# Finding element closest to mean in python list

Tags: python, list, pandas, numpy, mean

I have a list of some random numbers (integers and floats)

```
In[]:  list1
Out[]: [8.6, 9, 15, 20, 1]
```

I have found out the average/ mean value of the list:

```
m = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, list1) / len(list1)
```

This outputs 10.72  .

Now, I have to find the closest number to **avg** from the list **list1** .

In the above eg, from list1 the closes number to 10.72 is 9.

One way is to find the difference between the **avg** and **each element** in the list, and then look for the smallest difference and then output that element producing smallest difference, But I was looking for more crisp and efficient way, please suggest me one.

Comment: I guess : `a = np.asarray(list1)` and then : `a[np.abs(a - a.mean()).argmin()]`?

Comment: All the answers below in effect do what OP doesn't want to, but at least they do it crisply.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ what answers? :P

Comment: Woah... wtf....

Comment: Use an array version : `a = np.asarray(list1)` and use `a.mean()` to get that mean value and then the linked dup for the rest of the work.

Comment: If you want things to be more crisp and efficient, use `statistics.mean` (as of Python 3.4) rather than your own flavor of `reduce`. If you have to use an older version, at least use `sum` for the first part.

Comment: Use `sum` instead of implementing it yourself using `reduce`

Comment: The question referred in duplicate, doesn't really answer the question about efficiency, yet it provide nice answer using syntactic sugar of numpy, while has nothing to do with complexity efficient.

Comment: @ArtemBarger NumPy isn't just sugar, its underlying code is in C. So, unless you consider C as sugar too, I would have to disagree and should be as efficient as one could get staying in Python/NumPy.

Comment: answer in the link hides details, it makes two passes on list, while there is solution which can do it in one pass only, with some math trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [built-in min() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and find minimum distance from your number

```
min(list1, key=lambda x:abs(x-m))
```